# Can not import espeak

Tags: python, text, speech

For the past few days I have been trying to trying to get this "simple" voice synth to work. The code came in a manual for the raspberry pi. This is my first time really getting into python so my head is kinda spinning. Here is the code:

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["espeak"])

    from espeak import espeak 
    from tkinter import *
    from datetime import datetime

    def hello_world():
    espeak.synth("Hello World")

    def time_now():
    t = datetime.now().strftime("%K %M")
    espeak.synth("The time is %s"%t)

    def read_text():
    text_to_read = input_text.get()
    espeak.synth(text_to_read)

    def root_Tk():
    root.title("voice box")
    input_text = StrinVar()
    box = Frame(root, height = 200, width =500)
    box.pack_propagate(0)
    box.pack(padx = 5, pady =5)
    Label(box, text="Enter Text").pack()
entry_text = Entry(box, exportselection =0, textvariable = input_text,)
entry_text.pack()
entry_ready = Button(box, text = "Read this", command = read_text)
entry_ready.pack()
hello_button = Button(box, text = "Hello World", command = hello_world)
hello_button.pack()
time_button = Button(box, text = "What's the time?", command = time_now)
time_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the error message when I run it:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/espeak.py", line 4, in 
    from espeak import espeak
  File "/home/pi/espeak.py", line 4, in 
    from espeak import espeak
ImportError: cannot import name 'espeak'

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, I have a feeling im just making a simple newbie mistake. Hopefully I was able to post it to the forum correctly, the bottom part of the code is in line with the rest, but for some reason it's slightly off on here...

Comment: are you trying to import a module called `espeak` in a file called `espeak.py`? That's not advisable I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

Install espeak and the python-espeak package in Ubuntu with apt-get.

`sudo apt-get install espeak python-espeak`

In your .py file:

```
from espeak import espeak

def hello_world():
    espeak.synth("Hello World")

....
```

This will fix your issue!

Ref: http://www.devdungeon.com/content/text-speech-python-espeak

**Bonus**: You can consider using [gTTS](http://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/) instead of espeak as it maintained under Python package index.